# Comparing two Access tables identical in structure but not data

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in Access database, Table1 and Table2 with exactly the same structure but Table1 has more data. I want to figure out which data am I missing from Table2. The primary key for each table is composed of text fields:

- CenterName
- BuildingName
- FloorNo
- RoomNo

Each center can have many buildings and two different centers can have a building with the same name. Also room numbers and floor numbers can be the same across different buildings and different centers.

I have tried

```
SELECT t1.CenterName, t1.BuildingName, t1.FloorNo, t1.RoomNo, t2.CenterName
FROM Table1 as t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.CenterName=t2.CenterName 
WHERE t2.CenterName Is Null;
```

But the above does not return any data, meaning all the Centers are in both tables. But it does not tell me anything about the rest of the fields that might be missing from Table2.
Can anyone please help to re-write my query so it works as intended?

I am used to SQL Server database so building queries in Access is a bit time consuming for me. Before I transfer all the data into SQL Server for analysis I wanted to see if I can get any help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join on all four of the fields which make up the primary key.

```sql
SELECT
    t1.CenterName,
    t1.BuildingName,
    t1.FloorNo,
    t1.RoomNo,
    t2.CenterName
FROM
    Table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2
    ON
            t1.CenterName = t2.CenterName 
        AND t1.BuildingName = t2.BuildingName 
        AND t1.FloorNo = t2.FloorNo
        AND t1.RoomNo = t2.RoomNo
WHERE t2.CenterName Is Null;
```

Comment: I just now tested in Access 2010, created *Table1* and *Table2* with those 4 text fields as primary key in each.  Added data to those tables.  Pasted the SQL from this answer into SQL View of a new query ... and it ran without error, retrieving the *Table1* record which does not exist in *Table2*.  I don't understand why it fails for you.  If you post a copy of your db to a file sharing site, I'll look into it.

Comment: sorry, it was my bad, I made a typo. I ran it and it ran but crashed Access

Comment: Actually I ran it again and looks like it worked. Except it returns more rows than it should

Comment: Does that mean it returns *Table1* rows which do exist in *Table2*?